# how does h5 websocket work

Tags: c#, html, websocket

i have faced a problem about H5 websocket

this is my server code by c# , i have open a port 3030 to run socket

```
 WebSocketServer server = new WebSocketServer("ws://127.0.0.1:3030");
```

then in my website,i connected to server

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://www.yummyonline.net:3030");
```

but,the error throwed out

WebSocket connection to 'ws://www.yummyonline.net:3030/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

while i define like this  in my website

```
 var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:3030");
```

it will work.
could anyone can teach me why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tell your server to listen only on 127.0.0.1, therefore it will not be accepting connections on any other address or interface.

Try using WS://0.0.0.0:3030 as the binding to listen on all interfaces and addresses.

Comment: i  have try what you say, but in my remote server , it has connected successfully.  while in my local website , it throw                                         WebSocket connection to 'ws://www.yummyonline.net:3030/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: and the general only list  Request URL:ws://www.yummyonline.net:3030/      the most improtent is that it doesn't give me and status code!!!

Comment: Does that name resolve to the local machine's address locally?

Comment: oh,my god,i have't open the tcp port in Firewall.